# Unexpected NSTextFiled string deletion upon pressing period

Tags: swift, xcode, nstextfield

I have subclassed NSTextField and assigned a custom NumberFormatter to it. I read the content of the text field using the textDidChange() method. Everything works smoothly except if enter "." (as a decimal separator) in the text field, the entire text disappears. If I don't read the text, instead, this doesn't happen.

I tried to override some control functions inherited from NSControlTextEditingDelegate but I haven't found the one that reacts when I press ".".

Xcode Version 10.3 (10G8)

Swift 5

```swift
import Cocoa

class HRXNumbeField: NSTextField {
    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        self.formatter = HRXNumberFormatter()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        print(self.stringValue) // comment this line to avoid text deletion
    }
}

class HRXNumberFormatter: NumberFormatter {
    override func isPartialStringValid(_ partialString: String,
                                       newEditingString newString: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?,
                                       errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool {

        if partialString.count == 0 { return true }

        if let _ = Float(partialString) {
            return true
        }
        else {
            NSSound.beep()
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Try to comment the line in textDidChange() and see the difference.

Comment: Why do you want to get the string value of a number field in `textDidChange`? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the numberFormatter tries to validate the input to the text field when you access `stringValue` inside `textDidChange(_:)` and since `.` cannot be converted to a float, rejects the `.` character.

An easier way to enforce Decimal input than setting a custom `NumberFormatter` and overriding its `isPartialStringValid(_:newEditingString:errorDescription)` function is to simply override `textDidChange` and remove the invalid characters there.

```
class HRXNumberField: NSTextField {
    override func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        let invalidChars = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "1234567890.").inverted
        let validChars = stringValue.components(separatedBy: invalidChars)
        stringValue = validChars.joined()
        let separatedByDot = stringValue.components(separatedBy: ".")
        if separatedByDot.count > 2 {
            stringValue = separatedByDot[0] + "." + separatedByDot.dropFirst().joined()
        }
        print(self.stringValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you haven't tried to comment the line in my code, otherwise you would have seen that the formatter does accept the "." and correctly translates "X." into "X.0". Can you confirm that or did I not understand your answer (which seems not to be working)?

Comment: @Antonio_IT I did try commenting out that line and if you read my first paragraph carefully, you'll understand that I actually explain why that's the expected behaviour :) How is my answer not working on your side? I've tested it and it accepts decimal inputs and only those.

Comment: Even using your code, if I press "." the field is erased, which is what was happening also before. You said that X. cannot be converted to a float but that's incorrect. Try this in a playground `if let f = Float("3.") { print(f) }`. So, maybe you are using another version of swift?

Comment: Maybe I haven't been clear. Only if you read `self.stringValue` then the text field is erased. If you don't read the text, everything works fine (but what do I do with the text if I cannot read it?). Therefore, my number formatter does accept the dot already.

Comment: @Antonio_IT how are you testing the code from my answer? Even if I add `print(self.stringValue)` after the line `stringValue = validChars.joined(), the textfield keeps its value, it doesn't erase the `.`. I'm testing in a Playground using Swift 5

Comment: @Antonio_IT as for _"You said that X. cannot be converted to a float but that's incorrect."_, you're right, I wasn't completely precise, the `.` character cannot be converted to `Float`, which is the value of `partialString` when you input the `.` character.

Comment: My apologies. I didn't get the part in which I shouldn't use the number formatter. It's a workaround (partially) but not a fix. And it doesn't explain what you said anyway about `X.` conversion to float. The problem with your solution is one could add more than one dot. This is why number formatter exist. But thank you for trying.

Comment: @Antonio_IT check my updated answer, not it only allows the input of a single `.`.

Comment: Thanks! I just got to a similar solution. Yours is more elegant though. Still, it's a workaround which I have to use for now. I would love to know what triggers the text to disappear.

Comment: @Antonio_IT I've already explained what triggers that. The `isPartialStringValid` function gets called when you input `.` to your textfield. Then you do `Float(partialString)`, where `partialString` is `"."`, which obviously cannot be converted to `Float`, so that result will be `nil` and hence the validation returns `false`.

Comment: I have to insist. This is not what happens. If you put a breakpoint in my code at the line where the validation occurs you will see the "." is perfectly valid. Again, the text disappears ONLY if you try to read it! So, with my code, nothing is invalidated if you simply type a dot. Please, let me know if that's not clear yet

Answer (score 0):

Getting `self.stringValue` in `textDidChange` forces the formatter to execute `getObjectValue(_:for:errorDescription:)`. Get the string from the field editor instead.

```
override func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    super.textDidChange(notification)
    if let fieldEditor = self.currentEditor() {
        print(fieldEditor.string)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I just had time to test your solution. You did answer my question and solved the puzzle. However, it seems that adoption of your solution creates another problem. Namely, if I type any number with decimals I cannot move the focus to another number field in the same window. They are both instances of my `HRXNumbeField` class. If I type integers, I can freely move focus from one field to the other.

Comment: Does `isPartialStringValid` return `true`?

Comment: Yes, it does. You can type decimals with no problems.

Comment: Is the decimal seperator of the number formatter a point or a komma (localized, system prefs)? Does 123.456 work?

Comment: Yes, it works. The separator is the dot. Everything works as expected except I cannot move to another text field, neither with tab, nor by clicking on it. It's a very unpredictable behavior.

Comment: I think, somehow the formatter doesn't approve the number.

Comment: I have no idea but I cannot agree with you because if the formatter rejects the number then the character you just pressed is not displayed at all. Instead, in my case, it is displayed and stored correctly. Thank you for you help

Comment: The formatter checks the format in `getObjectValue(_:for:errorDescription:)` which is called at end editing. If Localize Format of the formatter is switched on and the decimal seperator in the system prefs is a komma then 12.34 is rejected.

Comment: How does this can be connected with the fact that the number seems valid but the focus is kept on the text field?

Comment: Any beeps? Did you implement or override any methods like `textShouldEndEditing(_:)`? What are the settings of the formatter? As a test, to be sure it's not the formatter, overrride `getObjectValue(_:for:errorDescription:)`, call `super` and print the result.

Comment: No beeps. It's too messy. Apple should make it more intuitive. I'm using the workaround suggested by Dávid and move on.